# How to pass a prop to all children and grandchildren of a certain type

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to have a parent component that has the ability to find all descendents of a certain React class type, and pass it a prop. So given a structure like this:

```
<Parent>
  <div>
    <em>
      <GimmeProps />
    </em>
  </div>
  <GimmeProps />
</Parent>
```

The `componentDidMount` method of `Parent` would be able to find all the `<GimmeProps>` elements and set them as such:

```
<GimmeProps magic={this.callback} />
```

How would I do this? I already tried using `React.Children.forEach` recursively, but I can't tell the React class type, and I don't think I can set props that way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `context`, not props. Context behaves in many ways just like props, but they are being passed from a component to all their children and grandchildren.

They can be accessed inside children using `this.context.foo`

Here's a blogpost explaining how to use props:
https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html

Official react documentation for context:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: `context` is at risk of being deprecated. I saw a discussion between React devs and none of them really like this part of the API.

Comment: @ffxsam, so what's the alternative? Having your own special `context` prop that each of the layers manually passes down?

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo Not sure what the alternative is, which is why I'm posting here. I could use a Flux architecture but I'm trying to keep these components 100% pure React.

Comment: Oh... sorry... I didn't notice you're the same one who posted the original question.